# My web app does not work in Azure - error 0x00000000

Tags: azure, iis, deployment, asp.net-core

I am trying to deploy an application in Azure http://iberodev.azurewebsites.net

The application uses Identity, IdentityServer4, Entity Framework Core, etc.
and it has some npm and bower dependencies and it uses gulp to generate CSS from SASS, etc.
Pretty standard web app.

**Everything works well in local**
I don't get any errors when publishing to Azure and I can see all my dll and wwwroot components are there.

When I access the application it shows a blank page. But I can see that the application is running (it returns favicon.ico, and it reaches middleware pipeline).

I enabled some logging in Azure and I can see than whenever I send a request to the app it causes a **500 internal server error**. But it does not give much details:

[image: printscreen of error]

error is 0x00000000

**Any idea on how can I better troubleshoot this issue or what might be?** I ran out of ideas.

This is my web.config in Azure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Iberodev.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- BEGIN rule TAG FOR HTTPS REDIRECT -->
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <!-- END rule TAG FOR HTTPS REDIRECT -->
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and my project.json is pretty simple too:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Iberodev.Common": "1.0.0",
    "Iberodev.Data": "1.0.0",
    "Iberodev.Data.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Iberodev.Web.Model": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "bower install",
      "dotnet bundle",
      "gulp clean",
      "gulp compile"
    ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

this is my startup class
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile(Constants.IberodevisSettings.SETTINGS_FILE_FULLNAME, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"{Constants.IberodevisSettings.SETTINGS_FILE_NAME}.{env.EnvironmentName}.{Constants.IberodevisSettings.SETTINGS_FILE_EXTENSION}", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        // AspNet Core Identity
        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(config => {
            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = Constants.IdentityValues.REQUIRE_UNIQUE_EMAIL;
            config.Password.RequiredLength = Constants.IdentityValues.PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH;
            config.Password.RequireDigit = Constants.IdentityValues.REQUIRE_DIGIT;
            config.Password.RequireUppercase = Constants.IdentityValues.REQUIRE_UPPERCASE;
            config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = Constants.IdentityValues.REQUIRE_NON_ALPHANUMERIC;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IberodevContext, Guid>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddUserStore<UserStore<User, Role, IberodevContext, Guid>>();

        //Add EF services
        services.AddDbContext<IberodevContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        });

        // Identity Server 4.
        services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddInMemoryStores()
        .AddInMemoryClients(ConfigInMemory.GetClients("http://localhost:8080"))
        .AddInMemoryScopes(ConfigInMemory.GetScopes())
        .AddAspNetIdentity<User>();

        // AspNet Core MVC
        services.AddMvc();

        BootstrapServices(services);
        BootstrapRepositories(services);
    }

    private void BootstrapServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    }

    private void BootstrapRepositories(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        var logLevel = env.IsDevelopment() ? LogLevel.Debug : LogLevel.Information;
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(logLevel);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        //ASP.NET Core Identity (adds cookie authentication)
        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseIdentityServer(); // it relies on the authentication cookie Identity creates, so it must be after.
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find more details by making Azure app believe that it's under development environment so that it can display development errors.
I added this key value pair in the Application Settings:
`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT     Development`

And I managed to see that the view Index was missing because I hadn't added views in publish options:

```
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
```